# present a controller with alpha is 0.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller

The new UIViewController named *vc* for example, then call

`[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

I want  *vc* looks like transparent or alpha = 0.5,

I know the code below can do that, bu the present animation disappear, I want both **transparent** and **annimation**, any idear?

`self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;`

Comment: Be careful animating new views in if they're not opaque - sometimes iOS uses opacity to hide the workings of its built-in animations, and introducing translucency can look really bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that is the best solution, but you could definitely do the animation yourself quite simply :

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
newVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
newVC.view.alpha = 0.5;    

[self addChildViewController:newVC];
[self.view addSubview:newVC.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    newVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you give opacity to view, all the button, label etc will also have opacity.**

***Follow below steps for what you want...***

*Give transparent color to view.*

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

*Then add uiimageview and give background color as transparent color and then say opacity as 0.5.*

```
myImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myImage.alpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: I want the ViewController that presented looks transparent, not the current ViewController.

Comment: @Geaka : okay, then use `yourView.backgroundColor`